# Blazor button event firing multiple times

Tags: c#, events, blazor, blazor-server-side

I havea blazor app in which a button event is triggered when pressed. The problem is that the event is fired 3 times each time you press the button. I just noticed that if I press Enter instead of clicking the button the event fires just once. (And I don't really know why...)

This is the button and some more html if needed:

```
    <div class="form-container uk-flex uk-flex-column uk-flex-middle">
        <span class="input-container">
            <input type="text" name="verb" id="form_verb" @bind="searchInput" />
        </span>
        <!-- This is the button -->
        <button type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-secondary" style="width:40%; margin-top:0.25rem;" @onclick="@Search">Lorem ipsum</button>
    </div>
    <h1>@counter</h1>
```

And this is the event that is fired:

```
private async Task Search()
{
    counter = counter + 1;
    navigatableSearchInput = searchInput;
    await tablaReconocimientos.SearchVerb(searchInput);
}
```

Here you have an example of whats going on:
[image]

EDIT_1: changed @onclick event with @onclick="@Search". Same behaviour.

EDIT_2: pressing enter behaviour added.

EDIT_3: markup for button clarification

Comment: Your example is a bit light on details, but can you change your button click handler to ```@onclick="@Search"``` and update your question with the result?

Comment: Just updated with your request. The behaviour still is the same. What else can I write here to give you more info? It is almost all the code in the page.

Comment: It looks to me like the button fires every time the page is rendered/updating and the real click. Can you attach your code for the button?

Comment: @Taladan the code for the button is above an so is the event that is fired. Were you talking about that? EDIT for the mark at the button component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Taladan mentioned above, the function was called every time the page was rendered or updating. I just didn't notice that I left a call to that function in `OnAfterRender()`. I just changed that part to be called in `OnParametersSet()` and worked like a charm.

I had this:

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (searchInput != null) Search();
}
```

And just changed to this

```
protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if (searchInput != null) Search();
    return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
}
```

Comment: Just to note, if you use OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) you can wrap the code inside this method with if(firstRender){...} and it should prevent this from continuously reloading.